# How to merge text having some content and leave blank lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have an address txt file on Ubuntu. Something like below -

```
Name
Address1
Address2
Address3

Name2
Address12
Address22
Address32
```

How can I merge the content as like -

```
Name Address1 Address2 Address3
Name2 Address12 Address22 Address32
```

Actually the addresses are written to a file one after another - like as mentioned above. A new address is separated by a new line or blank line. Now I want to merge for each address row into one line - and so repeatedly for all addresses

Comment: could you provide a broader example with the corresponding desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
Name Address1 Address2 Address3
Name2 Address12 Address22 Address32
Name3 Address13 Address23 Address33
```

By setting `RS` makes `awk` work with blocks of data as record.
`{$1=$1}1` reconstruct the line.

This fail if field starting with `0` (so less robust):

```
awk -v RS= '$1=$1' file
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was hoping to come up with, but I was trying to reconstitute the line using `$0 = $0`, which I now know (and thought there may be others who would like to take note) doesn't work for that.

Comment: @jas This is the same way I did learn linux,  see what other have done and using Google :)

Comment: +1 as this is exactly the right answer (though not leaving a space between `-v` and `RS=` makes it unnecessarily gawk-specific!).

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, did not know.  Learn some new today too, thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks .. this script is really a great one

Answer (score 4):

Setting `RS` to the empty string will use one or more blank lines as the record separator.

```
$ cat addr.txt
Name
Address1
Address2
Address3

Name2
Address12
Address22
Address32




Name3
Address13
Address23
Address33

$ awk 'BEGIN { RS="" } { gsub("\n"," ") }1' addr.txt
Name Address1 Address2 Address3
Name2 Address12 Address22 Address32
Name3 Address13 Address23 Address33
```

From the awk user's guide:

> **RS == ""**
>
> Records are separated by runs of blank lines. When FS is a single
>   character, then the newline character always serves as a field
>   separator, in addition to whatever value FS may have. Leading and
>   trailing newlines in a file are ignored.

Comment: Or just `awk -vRS= 'gsub("\n",FS)' file`

Comment: Very nice, @Jotne, although in the pathological case that an "address" has only one line, it won't be printed. Question: Is there anyway to avoid the gsub altogether and do something with OFS?

Comment: See my post.  No `gsub` is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v ORS=" " '{print}/^$/{printf("\n")}END{printf("\n")}' File
```

Set output record seperator (`ORS`) as `space`, print each line. Whenever an empty line is encountered, print `newline ("\n")`. Print `"\n"` in the `END` block to get desired output. Hope this is what u want.

**Sample:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat File
Name
Address1
Address2
Address3

Name2
Address12
Address22
Address32

Name2
Address12
Address22
Address32
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ awk -v ORS=" " '{print}/^$/{printf("\n")}END{printf("\n")}' File
Name Address1 Address2 Address3
Name2 Address12 Address22 Address32
Name2 Address12 Address22 Address32
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. But sometimes there are multiple blank lines also in between addressed which gets repeated - how can I delete the multiple blank line

Comment: this is not the way to approach this problem in awk, see the answer from @Jotne for the right approach.